# How to add custom error message in Power Virtual agent

Tags: power-virtual-agents

How can I add a custom error message like "wrong file name entered" when filename entered from power virtual agent bot as input to flow doesn't matches the filename  in onedrive ,I  have used find file in folder action within power automate flow,

this is my  [PVA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNkPs.jpg)

here is my flow [PowerAutomate flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWS2F.jpg)

I tried giving condition , but iam not able to reuturn 2 values from flow to PVA

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "Return Value To Power Virtual Agents" action to return one or more values from the flow back to a bot as per below screenshot.

Please see more details on [output parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-flow#output-parameters) from the official documentation.

[image: Return value]